# Reason for rc<boot_facility> named symbolic links in OpenSUSE

Tags: opensuse, init

OpenSUSE 11.4 has `rc<boot_facility>` named symbolic links in `/usr/bin/`, `/usr/sbin/` and `/sbin/` directories:

```
# find / -type l -iname "rc*"
/etc/rc.d
/usr/bin/rcs2log
/usr/sbin/rcmysql
/usr/sbin/rcpcscd
/usr/sbin/rcsnmpd
/usr/sbin/rchal
/usr/sbin/rcntp
/usr/sbin/rcraw
/usr/sbin/rcfirewall
/usr/sbin/rcpowerfail
/usr/sbin/rccpufreq
/usr/sbin/rcsendmail
/usr/sbin/rcatftpd
/usr/sbin/rcdbus
/usr/sbin/rccron
/usr/sbin/rcnscd
/usr/sbin/rcsshd
/usr/sbin/rcsetserial
/usr/sbin/rcjuniper-backup
/usr/sbin/rcmdadmd
/usr/sbin/rcirq_balancer
/usr/sbin/rcrandom
/usr/sbin/rcsingle
/usr/sbin/rcrsyncd
/usr/sbin/rcsplash
/usr/sbin/rcapache2
/usr/sbin/rcrpmconfigcheck
/sbin/rcfbset
/sbin/rckbd
/sbin/rccrypto
/sbin/rcnetwork
/sbin/rcsyslog
#
```

What is the reason for `rc<boot_facility>` named symbolic links pointing to corresponding System-V type init scripts in `/etc/initd/` directory? Which utilities/scripts use those symlinks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't that to ease typing the service command for admin? Instead of typing something like `/etc/init.d/svc reload`, they just use `rcsvc reload` directly. At least some quick googling confirms that.